# Multiple notifications with MediatR and Autofac ContravariantRegistrationSource

Tags: autofac, contravariance, mediatr

I am trying to use MediatR to set up generic notifications, but the notification handler is being called multiple times.

https://github.com/smartaypants/MediatR/blob/master/test/MediatR.Tests/CustomNotificationTests.cs

The test publishes a CustomNotification which implements ICustomNotification. The CustomNotificationHandler is constrained to accept TNotification which must implement ICustomNotification.

I would expect this to only be called once but the handler is being called 3 times - where TNotification is CustomNotification, CustomNotificationBase and ICustomNotification - but they are all the same instance... should that happen?

If I remove the ContravariantRegistrationSource line from the Autofac registration then it works as expected. Similarly if I use the StructureMap registration it works fine.

I don't entirely understand why I need to enable contravariance. I am only using this line because it is included on the MediatR wiki and almost every example I can find.

Please can someone explain why this is happening and if I am doing something wrong, or is it a bug in Autofac. Thanks.